# laravel validation required if

Tags: php, laravel-5, validação

```
'tipo'              => 'required',
'cpf'               => 'required_if:tipo,F|cpf',
'rg'                => 'required_if:tipo,F',
'cnpj'              => 'required_if:tipo,J|cnpj',
'inscricao_estadual'=> 'required_if:tipo,J',
```

Seguinte, estou usando esse `required if`, e quando o *request* vem com tipo 'J' ele valida no cpf, como resolver?

Comment: O que exatamente acontece, talvez seja o segundo validação que ele executa!

Comment: mas existe uma maneira do required if se extender pro cpf. Pois quando tipo for 'J' não quero que valide cpf.

Answer (score 3):

O `required_if` também pode ser usado dessa forma:
  `required_if:<field>,<comparador>,<valor>`

Exemplo:

```
'field1' => 'required|numeric',
'field2' => 'required_if:field1,==,2|string'
```

No seu caso, acredito que uma condição concatenada a string poderia resolver, exemplo:

```
Valitador::make($request->all(), [
  'tipo'              => 'required',
  'cpf'               => ($request['tipo']=='F' ? 'required|cpf' : 'nullable'),
  'rg'                => 'required_if:tipo,==,F',
  'cnpj'              => ($request['tipo']=='J' ? 'required|cnpj' : 'nullable'),
  'inscricao_estadual'=> 'required_if:tipo,==,J'
]);
```